# Using any array

Tags: arrays

Using google scripts in google sheets.I'm trying to use an arrary that has zip codes in it to look at a certain field and if that field matches one of the values in the array then it will proceed otherwise i'll keep going. I can't seems to figure that out. I'm having issues with the .indexOf function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    var tzip = new Array("02703", "02763", "02019", "01504", "02712", "02720");

    var dzip = new Array("02721", "02722", "02723", "02724", "02035", "02038");

    var row = data[i];

    var emailAddress = row[18]; // First column

    var message = "Hello"

    var emailSent = row[19]; // Third column    
    var leadsent = row[20];
    if (emailAddress == "Oil Sales" && tzip.indexOf(row[9] != 1) && emailSent != LEAD_SENT && leadsent != LEAD_COPIED) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you misplaced a parenthesis here: tzip.indexOf(row[9] !=1)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however that doesn't fix my issue

Comment: It does. re-read it please.

Comment: If the value in the cell is say 02721 which isn't in tzip it stills the script, which I'm trying to get it only run if the value in Row[9] is equal to what is in the array tzip. even if it now reads tzip.indexOf(row[9]) !=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had `tzip.indexOf(row[9] != 1)` where `row[9] != 1` will evaluate to a Boolean value. This means that you will be searching `tzip` for the index of a Boolean value.

If you change that to

```
tzip.indexOf(row[9]) != 1
```

then the value of `row[9]` can be at any index in `tzip` **except for index 1**.

I think what you meant was

```
tzip.indexOf(row[9]) != -1
```

since the `indexOf` function returns the index -1 if the value `row[9]` is not contained in `tzip`.

Comment: If the value in the cell is say 02721 which isn't in tzip it stills the script, which I'm trying to get it only run if the value in Row[9] is equal to what is in the array tzip

Comment: I did your suggested edit of if (emailAddress == "Oil Sales" && tzip.indexOf(row[9])!= -1 && emailSent != LEAD_SENT && leadsent != LEAD_COPIED). And it isn't doing anything now lol. I have one row that has a value found in ztip and one that doesn't and neither are doing anything now.